# Error input string was not in correct formalt

Tags: c#

I am making a c-sharp application that converts the distance units. 
My application prompts the error: "Input string was not in a correct format". As I'm new with the language I would appreciate some assistance.

This is the code I'm using:

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0) {
                label2.Text = "Miles";
                label3.Text = "kilometers";

                double m;
                double kilometer=1.6093 ;

                m = kilometer * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);//here is the problem 
                textBox2.Text = m.ToString();
```

Comment: Did you check what the string is?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add the error as text instead of a screenshot. Your question should also include what input caused the error. What was in textBox1?

Comment: looks like the value of `textBox1.Text` is not a in a valid format to convert to a double.

Comment: Quick question @Captain, what is the value of in the textbox..? you should initialize to a value of 0.0 or add code that checks `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(extBox1.Text))` then return else do your conversion

Comment: i think some one should ask a question about this problem and answer it perfectly so we make any questions like this as a duplicate. just like Null reference exception.or make it duplicate if there is any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just you need to check the value of your textbox first cause you can`t convert null value to Double

```
if (textBox1.Text!="")
                {
                    m = kilometer * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);//here is the problem 
                    textBox2.Text = m.ToString();
                }
```

or give textBox1 initial value before start calculation,
Note: If you use number Regex for TextBox1 this will be better
Thanks.